# Not getting Authorization dialog for App Script accessing BigQuery Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, authorization

I am trying to fix some App Scripts which use the BigQuery "Advanced Service" to install some BigQuery jobs.  The first new script I ran popped a BigQuery authorization dialog, and everything worked fine, now running hourly.  The second new script ran initially, but is now failing with:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

This began about 12 hours after the initial authorization, so it seems like something expired.  But, I can't figure out how to trigger the authorization dialog to appear.  Also, I expected an authorization would be required for each distinct function, yet the second one initially ran without asking for BigQuery permissions.

Additional Info:
Here is the .gs file I am executing:

```
function runQuery() {
  var projectId = redacted;

  var configuration = {
    "query": {
      "useQueryCache": false,
      "destinationTable": {
          "projectId": projectId,
          "datasetId": redacted,
          "tableId": redacted
        },
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
      "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
      "allowLargeResults": true,
      "query": redacted
    }
  };
  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
  };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  var jobId = jobResult.jobReference.jobId;
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}
```

The first time I ran a very similar query, I got a dialog prompting me for BigQuery permissions, as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization
I subsequently ran this same script successfully (with slightly different query config).  But, then, about 12 hours after first run, I started getting the authorization return quoted above.  I thought it might refresh with time, but still get same failure.

Comment: Do you have a refresh token?

Comment: @noogui, not that I know of.  My understanding is the App Scripts - BigQuery Advanced Service integration handles authorization for you, as I experienced initially, when it prompted me for permission.

Comment: Please include the code where you authorize your script - login, etc. People can't help you if you just say "script" because we've no idea how you're implementing it.

Comment: @noogui I had edited original to include more detail.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the query that you are running? I would suggest you to use [library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2), in this way you can manage your access in your scirpt.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this has been working all along.  The authorization error was being generated by my attempt to look at the job results, not by the job itself.  Doh!